# I'm looking for an "old" font but have had no luck finding it

Tags: fonts

I have been looking for a font like the one shown in the image below. I said it was an "old" font because the book is from the late 1800's. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Looks very similar to Old Standard, which is in TeX Live. The Æ is different, though.

Comment: See also the commercial Monotype Modern.